# Dynamic Response using Wiremock .NET C#

Tags: c#, wiremock

I have recently started using wiremock .net to create a mock API which is going to be run in kubernetes. I have this line in my code which is ran when the Wiremock server is started:

```cs
server
  .Given(
    Request.Create()
      .WithPath(_urlPath)
      .UsingPost()
      .WithBody(new XPathMatcher($"{_surname}='TestResponse'"))
  )
 .RespondWith(Response.Create()
   .WithStatusCode(200)
   .WithHeader("content-type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8")
   .WithBody(GetTestData())
);
```

In my Test Data response I have a CreatedDateTime. I was wondering is there an effective way to change this everytime a resquest is sent to the wiremock test server?

I currently have my code in a while loop which constanly reads the response file and calls a function to update the date in the response. It works but i was wondering of there is a better way please.

```
while (server.IsStarted)
{
    MockSetup.MockResponses(server);
    MockSetup.UpdateDates();
    Console.WriteLine("Mock Running");
    Thread.Sleep(30000);
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [response templating](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/Response-Templating) using [Handlebars.Net.Helpers](https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net.Helpers) to generate a new [DateTime](https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net.Helpers/wiki/DateTime).

Example:

```
{{DateTime.Now}}

// or

{{DateTime.Now \"yyyy-MM-dd\"}}
```